# java.nio.file Files.move() is copying instead of moving

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to use Java NIO Files.move method to move a directory.  It does copy the directory contents to the new location, but it leaves the old directory in place.  I would consider this a copy operation and not a move operation.

Any ideas why this is happening?  Here is my code:

```
Path source = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\test-source");
Path destination = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\test-destination");
try {
    System.out.println("Moving files ...");
    Files.move(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
    System.out.println("Done.");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Moving failed: " + e.toString());
}
```

Again, the destination directory appears with all its contents, but the source folder remains in place.

Comment: try StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ? did you try that?

Comment: `C:\test-source` should be `C:\\test-source`

Comment: When you say "it leaves the old directory in place" do you mean it leaves the files in the old directory? Or just the directory itself?

Comment: @Klitos Kyricou The source directory AND files remain.

Comment: @chengpohi It actually is C:\\ but I tried to obscure the actual name and location of my files before posting and forgot the second \.  Thanks for pointing that out.  I will edit the question.

Comment: I think it should work, and ATOMIC_MOVE is indeed what you want. It won't work if your actual source and destination directories are on different drives, or if the destination directory doesn't exist, or if the destination files already exist.

Comment: I tried it on Windows 10 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the code is correct.  But the source folder is not being deleted because another process is still working with that folder.  When I eliminate the other process (an AWS S3 directory download to the source folder), the move happens as I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

From 
[this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html)

ATOMIC_MOVE is a file operation.

```
public static final StandardCopyOption ATOMIC_MOVE
```

Move the file as an atomic file system operation.

Try `StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING`

Comment: I should have indicated that I tried the REPLACE_EXISTING option already.  Not only is it not the functionality I am looking for, it also does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this problem with Apache Lucene when trying to commit an `IndexWriter`. The problem was an `IndexSearcher` opened on the directory, resulting in a `java.nio.file.atomicmovenotsupportedexception`. The `IndexReader` constructor argument was provided by `DirectoryReader.open(Directory directory)`. Changing to use the overload `DirectoryReader.open(IndexWriter writer)` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a zipFileSystem but discovered I needed to call fileSystem.close() before it actually got removed from the zip.